# NoMethodError (undefined method `build' for #<Class:0x00000006371f30>)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, inherited-resources

I use `angularjs` and `InheritedResources gem` in my new rails project. I want use association in this project. I find `Singletons` for association with `InheritedResources`. I create 2 model and complete them like below:

`districts_controller.rb`:

```
class DistrictsController < InheritedResources::Base
  respond_to :json

  def district_params
    params.require(:district).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

`calculations_controller.rb`:

```
class CalculationsController < InheritedResources::Base
  respond_to :json
  singleton_belongs_to :district
  def calculation_params
    params.require(:calculation).permit(:district_id, :price)
  end
end
```

and  have a `model.js` in my `angularjs` code that create url and post data to rails application:

`model.js`:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app');
app.factory('District', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/districts/:id', {id: '@id'});
}]);

app.factory('Calculation', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('/districts/:district_id/calculations/:id', {district_id: '@district_id', id: '@id'});
}]);
```

I set `config/routes/rb` like below:

```
resources :districts, :defaults => {format: :json} do
    resources :calculations, :defaults => {format: :json}
  end
```

and `rake routes`:

```
district_calculations GET    /districts/:district_id/calculations(.:format) calculations#index {:format=>:json}
                      POST   /districts/:district_id/calculations(.:format) calculations#create {:format=>:json}
```

But when I post data from `angularjs` to `rails application`, data are recieved to rails server, but when rails server want to save data to database, I get below error:

```
Started POST "/districts/17/calculations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-10 12:56:53 +
0430
Processing by CalculationsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"district_id"=>"17", "price"=>";sadkas", "calculation"=>{"distric
t_id"=>"17", "price"=>";sadkas"}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `build' for #<Class:0x00000006371f30>)
```

If I used rails controller without `InheritedResorces`, I know I have to use `build` method instead of `new`, but I don't know how can I fix this problem. Any idea?!